# How to add 'select one...' to options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my select-form that works properly.

When the user loads the page it shall show an initial ‘select one...’ with value null or ‘’.

I tried to add it to the Object but wasn’t able to and would be glad to get help!

Thanks a lot!

---

**In my view:**

```
= select_tag 'incident[fault_id]' , options_from_collection_for_select( Fault.all, :id, :label)
```

I use Rails 3.2 and HAML

---

**Update:**

By chance I found something really sweet:

```
include_blank: 'select one...'
```

or completely

```
= f.collection_select :fault_id, Fault.order(:label), :id, :label, include_blank: 'select one...'
```

In case one likes that too...

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: you could move your "inline" answer to a real answer to the question, so that people can vote for it.  Unfortunately :include_blank or :prompt are only available with rails 3.x+

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) returns a string of option tags that have been compiled by iterating over the collection and assigning the result of a call to the value_method as the option value and the text_method as the option text.

So just prepend it with "select_one" option string without value:

```
 = select_tag 'incident[fault_id]', content_tag(:option,'select one...',:value=>"")+options_from_collection_for_select( Fault.all, :id, :label)
```

Comment: sweet finally an options that works with rails 2.x  with 3.x use :include_blank or what not I believe...

Comment: Whilst this works it would be more correct to use the 'prompt' option as commented below.

Comment: Before voting for this answer, check @dabobert's answer first - the better one

Answer (score 27):

`:prompt` is a property of `select_tag` *not* of `options_from_collect_for_select` so

```
select_tag("sales_rep[manufacturer_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@manufacturers, "id", "name"), { :prompt => 'Select Manufacturer' })
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: @dabobert is there a way to disable the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
collection_select(:sales_rep, :manufacturer_id, @manufacturers, :id, :name, { :prompt => 'Select Manufacturer' })
```